# Why is my elements in my vector of objects not updating upon calling one of the objects member function?

Tags: c++, vector, member-functions

I have been trying to do debug this for a long time using visual studio debugger but I can't figure out why my function `emp.setHoursWorked(hWorked);` in `recordHoursWorkedForEmployee` only seems to be update `numOfHoursWorked` while in `recordHoursWorkedForEmployee`, as soon the program exits the function the `numOfHoursWorked` of all Employees in the vector go back to 0. Below is the code in question. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#ifndef PAYROLLSYSTEM   
#define PAYROLLSYSTEM
#include "Employee.h"
#include "Paycheck.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class PayRollSystem
{
public:

    //custom constructor gets company name
    PayRollSystem(string);
    void createEmployee(string, string,string, double);
    void removeEmployee(string);
    void recordHoursWorkedForEmployee(string);
    void issuePaychecks();


private:
    string companyName;
    vector<Employee> companyEmployees;
};
#endif



void PayRollSystem::createEmployee(string empId, string fName, string lName, double hWage)
{
    Employee temEmp = Employee(empId, fName, lName, hWage);
    companyEmployees.push_back(temEmp);

}


void PayRollSystem::recordHoursWorkedForEmployee(string empId)
{

    for (Employee emp : companyEmployees)
    {

        if (emp.getEmployeeId() == empId)
        {
            int hWorked = 0;
            cout << "What are the hours the worked for " + emp.getEmployeeId() + " during current pay period?" << endl;
            cin >> hWorked;

            //TODO: For some reason this line is not updating the hours worked. Must fix!
            emp.setHoursWorked(hWorked);
            cout << "Hours for " + emp.getEmployeeId() + " have been changed to " << emp.getHoursWorked() << endl;
        }
    }

}
```

**I excluded the header file here in order to not paste too many things not relevant to the problem i'm facing, only implementations of member functions relevant to the problem provided**

```
//Overloaded constructor to be used with PayRollSystem
Employee::Employee(string empId, string fName, string lName, double hWage)
{
    employeeId = empId;
    firstName = fName;
    lastName = lName;
    hourlyWage = hWage;
    numOfHoursWorked = 0;

}

void Employee::setHoursWorked(int hWorked)
{
    if (hWorked >= 0)
        numOfHoursWorked = hWorked;
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid number of hours worked." << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

string Employee::getEmployeeId() const
{
    return employeeId;
}
```

Comment: `for (Employee& emp : companyEmployees)` Note the very important `&`, otherwise you're making a copy of each item, changing it, and immediately discarding it when it goes out of scope.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line makes a copy of each employee:

```
for (Employee emp : companyEmployees)
```

The variable `emp` is a copy of the object in the container. So if you update this you are only updating the copy. Each iteration you get a new value copied into `emp` but any changes are not reflected in the original object.

You probably meant:

```
for (Employee& emp : companyEmployees)
            ^^^
```

Here `emp` is a reference to the object inside the vector. If you modify this you are modifying the original value inside the vector.